# How to create a string query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i was given a homework problem to be able to create a query string based on certain parameters in an array? I am still fairly new to javascript so have some success with it but would appreciate if someone can check my code please. Thank you to everyone in advance.

I am using forEach to loop through the array to get the values and using string concatenation to get some url. I have made a sample codepen for it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmRXzg

```js
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam', 'Daisy'],
  food: ['banana', 'Apple']
}

let handler = Object.entries(Person)

handler.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element)
})

let myUrl = Object.entries(handler).map(key => key + '=' +
  handler[key]).join('&')
let visitUrl = "http://someURLString/?" + myUrl
console.log(myUrl)
console.log(visitUrl)
```

How can i get my final result to look like

```
someUrlString/?name=Sam,Daisy&food=banana,apple
```

Comment: FYI, if your code works and you are seeking improvements, CodeReview is the site for it

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I really appreciate the help but i was actually able to figure it out. Thank you so much. If you want to, you can go ahead and delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` on `Object.entries()` and then `join()` entries by `=` and then join result by `&`

```js
let Person = {
   name: ['Sam','Daisy'],
  food: ['banana','Apple']
 }
 
let res = Object.entries(Person).map(x=> x.join('=')).join('&');

console.log(res)
```

#### Explanation:

`Object.entiries()` return an array of arrays. Each array contain key value pair. In this case entries will be `[['name', ['Sam','Daisy']], ['food', ['banana','Apple']]]`.

Now we use `map()` on array. `map()` is takes a callback. It that callback first argument(in above case its `x`) is current element of array through which we are iterating. `map()` creates **new array of same length** based on the value returned from callback. In above case value returned is  `x.join('=')`

`join()` is method which converts array to string by adding a given substring b/w each of them. So when apply `join()` on

```
[food , ['banana','Apple']].join('=')
```

it will become

```
"food=banana,Apple"
```

The array `['banana','Apple']` is converted to a string implicitly. So `['banana','Apple']` is `banana,Apple`

In the last part we get array `["name=Sam,Daisy","food=banana,Apple"]` and we `join()` it by `&`.

The point is that when we array is converted to string. It returns string in which all elements are separated by `,`

Comment: thank you so much. this was what i needed. Could you please explain how this works? that would help me for future references. And how it is different than template strings?

Comment: Entries get each key and value and places them in an array, for example the first entry would be this:
`['name', ['sam', 'daisy']`

Then `.map()` is like a for loop, except it returns an array of items from the callback function. Here Maheer has used x as an identifier for each entry. So, he uses `.join()` to join the items in the array, delimited by an `=`, which results in `name=Sam,Daisy`. Then this same function happens for each of the other entries, then he ends it with another `.join()`. So, he will join the new entries with a &, resulting in `name=Sam,Daisy&food=banana,Apple`

Comment: @KobanDavis ohhh i see . damnn you guys are really good lol. Thank you.

Comment: You'll get there in no time. Understanding why a function works is the only way to learn, so keep it up 

Comment: @paaswhatever I have added a detailed explanation make sure to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `.entries`, `.map` and `.join` to:

- Map [key,value] pairs of Person.
- Transform their value to a single string, by eventually manipulating data.
- Join them to return the final string.

```js
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam', 'Daisy'],
  food: ['banana', 'Apple']
}

const res = Object.entries(Person).map(([entryName, entryValues]) => {
  return `${entryName}=${entryValues.map(i => i.toLowerCase()).join(',')}`;
}).join('&');

const url = `someUrlString/?${res}`;

console.log(url);
```